# Transfer swift packages to another project

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a project which contains ~10 swift packages.

Now I want to create another project with the same packages set. Copying manually is not convenient because there are a lot of packages and xcode doesn't allow to copy their urls in UI.

There is a `Package.resolved` file but it contains a flat array where swift packages are mixed with their dependencies.

There is also section `/* Begin XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference section */` inside `project.pbxproj` which contains exactly all the necessary packages but you can't just take them and move to another project.

Are there more convenient ways to do that? For example if you use cocoapods you just copy contents of podfile.

Comment: "For example if you use cocoapods you just copy contents of podfile." How about copying Package.swift. That's the counterpart of the Podfile in SPM.

Comment: packages as in local packages?

Comment: "which contains exactly all the necessary packages but you can't just take them and move to another project" I think you can. It's just really cumbersome to do, because the sections you need to copy are scattered in several places.

Comment: You can also try out tools like [mod-pbxproj](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj) to write a script that copies packages from one project to another.

Comment: @Sweeper where is `Package.swift` in a common project? Seems SPM doesn't create it in a common project but in package targets only

Comment: Yeah I later realised you probably did not create a package project, see my other two comments.

Comment: If you plan on reusing the same setup over several packages why not create your own package with all the packages? Then you can have a local or published package with all you need.

Comment: @loremipsum The problem is if they will differ at least with one included package (in future) then I can't create a package-container.

Comment: If you create your own local package you can copy and paste the Package file just like you would with a pod. Creating a package is easier than going through the whole pod setup. It wouldn’t take much work